# iAd like popup view in ios app

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, iad

i am trying to develop a app that will load a iAd like popup view that will show a webview with a image in it. what i mean is that it will load a JPG or PNG url in it. i successfully created that popup but webview in not showing image in it can anyone please debug my code. i will post it here.

MainViewController.m

```
-(IBAction)openPopupWithURL
{
    [MTPopupWindow showWindowWithHTMLFile:@"http://URL/ad.php" insideView:self.view];
}
```

PopUpWindow.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface MTPopupWindow : NSObject
{
    UIView* bgView;
    UIView* bigPanelView;
}
+(void)showWindowWithHTMLFile:(NSString*)fileName insideView:(UIView*)view;
@end
```

PopUpWindow.m

```
#import "MTPopupWindow.h"
#define kShadeViewTag 1000
@interface MTPopupWindow(Private)
- (id)initWithSuperview:(UIView*)sview andFile:(NSString*)fName;
@end
@implementation MTPopupWindow
/**
 * This is the only public method, it opens a popup window and loads the given content
 * @param NSString* fileName provide a file name to load a file from the app resources, or a URL to load a web page
 * @param UIView* view provide a UIViewController's view here (or other view)
 */
+(void)showWindowWithHTMLFile:(NSString*)fileName insideView:(UIView*)view
{
    [[MTPopupWindow alloc] initWithSuperview:view andFile:fileName];
}

/**
 * Initializes the class instance, gets a view where the window will pop up in
 * and a file name/ URL
 */
- (id)initWithSuperview:(UIView*)sview andFile:(NSString*)fName
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code here.
        bgView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: sview.bounds] autorelease];
        [sview addSubview: bgView];

        // proceed with animation after the bgView was added
        [self performSelector:@selector(doTransitionWithContentFile:) withObject:fName afterDelay:0.1];
    }

    return self;
}

/**
 * Afrer the window background is added to the UI the window can animate in
 * and load the UIWebView
 */
-(void)doTransitionWithContentFile:(NSString*)fName
{
    //faux view
    UIView* fauxView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(10, 10, 200, 200)] autorelease];
    [bgView addSubview: fauxView];

    //the new panel
    bigPanelView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, bgView.frame.size.width, bgView.frame.size.height)] autorelease];
    bigPanelView.center = CGPointMake( bgView.frame.size.width/2, bgView.frame.size.height/2);

    //add the window background
    UIImageView* background = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"popupWindowBack.png"]] autorelease];
    background.center = CGPointMake(bigPanelView.frame.size.width/2, bigPanelView.frame.size.height/2);
    [bigPanelView addSubview: background];

    //add the web view
    int webOffset = 10;
    UIWebView* web = [[[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectInset(background.frame, webOffset, webOffset)] autorelease];
    web.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    if ([fName hasPrefix:@"http"]) {
        //load a web page
        web.scalesPageToFit = YES;
        [web loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString: fName]]];
    } else {
        //load a local file
        NSError* error = nil;
        NSString* fileContents = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:fName] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error: &error];
        if (error!=NULL) {
            NSLog(@"error loading %@: %@", fName, [error localizedDescription]);
        } else {
            [web loadHTMLString: fileContents baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"file://"]];
        }
    }

    [bigPanelView addSubview: web];

    //add the close button
    int closeBtnOffset = 10;
    UIImage* closeBtnImg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"popupCloseBtn.png"];
    UIButton* closeBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [closeBtn setImage:closeBtnImg forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [closeBtn setFrame:CGRectMake( background.frame.origin.x + background.frame.size.width - closeBtnImg.size.width - closeBtnOffset, 
                                   background.frame.origin.y ,
                                   closeBtnImg.size.width + closeBtnOffset, 
                                   closeBtnImg.size.height + closeBtnOffset)];
    [closeBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(closePopupWindow) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [bigPanelView addSubview: closeBtn];

    //animation options
    UIViewAnimationOptions options = UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight |
                                        UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction    |
                                        UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState;

    //run the animation
    [UIView transitionFromView:fauxView toView:bigPanelView duration:0.5 options:options completion: ^(BOOL finished) {

        //dim the contents behind the popup window
        UIView* shadeView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:bigPanelView.frame] autorelease];
        shadeView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        shadeView.alpha = 0.3;
        shadeView.tag = kShadeViewTag;
        [bigPanelView addSubview: shadeView];
        [bigPanelView sendSubviewToBack: shadeView];
    }];
}

/**
 * Removes the window background and calls the animation of the window
 */
-(void)closePopupWindow
{
    //remove the shade
    [[bigPanelView viewWithTag: kShadeViewTag] removeFromSuperview];    
    [self performSelector:@selector(closePopupWindowAnimate) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];

}

/**
 * Animates the window and when done removes all views from the view hierarchy
 * since they are all only retained by their superview this also deallocates them
 * finally deallocate the class instance
 */
-(void)closePopupWindowAnimate
{

    //faux view
    __block UIView* fauxView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(10, 10, 200, 200)];
    [bgView addSubview: fauxView];

    //run the animation
    UIViewAnimationOptions options = UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft |
    UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction    |
    UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState;

    //hold to the bigPanelView, because it'll be removed during the animation
    [bigPanelView retain];

    [UIView transitionFromView:bigPanelView toView:fauxView duration:0.5 options:options completion:^(BOOL finished) {

        //when popup is closed, remove all the views
        for (UIView* child in bigPanelView.subviews) {
            [child removeFromSuperview];
        }
        for (UIView* child in bgView.subviews) {
            [child removeFromSuperview];
        }
        [bigPanelView release];
        [bgView removeFromSuperview];

        [self release];
    }];
}

@end
```

and this is output
[image: No Images :(]

My ad.php

```
<?php
include("../includes/opencon.php");
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Mobile Ad</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$setting = mysql_fetch_object(mysql_query("select * from my_settings where id=1"));
?>
<img src="http://url.com/media/<?=$setting->image?>" style="width:100%; height:auto;"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please provide additional information, whether this happens when loading a local or remote image. I think for local images you could adjust your base url of the webview.

If you want to load local images, please provide the base URL of the App bundle:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
[webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:baseURL];
```

So instead of:

```
[web loadHTMLString: fileContents baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"file://"]];
```

use the app bundle url:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
[web loadHTMLString: fileContents baseURL:baseURL];
```

For further debugging, you could set the webview's [delegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) to your view and check, what the webview's content looks like:

```
web.delegate = self;
```

To now use the delegate implement the following:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    NSString *html = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.documentElement.outerHTML"];
    NSLog(@"%@",html);
}
```

Alternatively, go to Safari->Develop->iPhone Simulator/iOS Device->Webview
And take a look at the source code in the debug console of safari.

Comment: Thanks for replying. well this is happening when i am loading a remote image which i placed in a php file. so actually i am loading a webpage with a single image in it.

Comment: What does the html look like, which was loaded in the webview? - please check this.

Comment: Well, thats the "backend"-sourcecode - but how does the HTML look like, which is loaded by the Frontent (the webview of your app). Could you check this, by loading the URL, you want to load from the webview in a browser ?

Comment: Thanks i figured it out by myself.